# db_update() with joins

Tags: 7, database

Is there any way to `db_update()` for the following query?

```
UPDATE field_data_field_TEST as ft 
left join node as n on ft.entity_id = n.nid
set n.type='test'
where n.type='foo'
```

I tried using `db_update()->join();` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`db_update()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/class/UpdateQuery/7) doesn't implement any interfaces that have `join()`/`innerJoin()`/etc. methods so I think you're stuck with using `db_query()` and writing the query string out manually.

```
$sql = "
  UPDATE field_data_field_TEST as ft 
  left join node as n on ft.entity_id = n.nid
  set n.type = :type1
  where n.type = :type2";

$args = array(':type1' => 'test', ':type2' => 'foo');
db_query($sql, $args);
```

Comment: it is a workaround but in the drupal documentation they say "Do not use this function for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE queries. Those should be handled via db_insert(), db_update() and db_delete()respectively." so i think maybe to implement a subquery would be less performance but more correctly. What do you think ?

Comment: I'd take that documentation with a pinch of salt...if DBTNG can't perform the query you need with an existing class, it's perfectly acceptable to use `db_query()`. If you want to stick rigidly to the documentation then sure, a condition with a subquery would be an option. But as you say, it would be less performant and to me doesn't fell any 'better' than using a straight sql query

Comment: Just noting this appears to be also the case in Drupal 8, `Update` doesn't implement any `join` functions, still need to use the generic query for this case.